# What is the difference between "do more harm than good" and "has more bad to it than good"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms

What is the difference between "do more harm than good" and "has more bad to it than good"? Do they literally mean "have more disadvantages than advantages"?

Are they informal?

Comment: *Harm* is transitive. It's not the intrinsic qualities that are being assessed, but the effects those intrinsic qualities will have.

Comment: What about formality? Can both expressions be used in formal contexts?

Comment: I've not heard the second phrase very much, the first is a common phrase.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Ngram doesn't allow searching for phrases longer than 5 words.

Answer (score 1):

"Do more harm than good" implies that whatever is happening will *result* in more bad than good (the word harm could be replaced by bad; it's the *do* that matters). I've never actually heard "has more bad to it than good", but to me it sounds like it's describing a *quality* of something rather than the *effect*.